# How can I connect child function with parent function in same class?

Tags: python, function, class

```
class NewsSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'test12'
allowed_domains = ['news.daum.net']
start_urls = ['https://news.daum.net/breakingnews/digital']


rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/breakingnews/digital\?page=\d$'),
         callback='parse_parent'),
]

def parse_parent(self, response):

    self.logger.info('Parent Response URL : %s' % response.url)

    for url in response.css('ul.list_news2.list_allnews > li > div'):

        article_url = url.css(
            'strong > a::attr(href)').extract_first().strip()

        yield scrapy.Request(article_url, self.parse_child, meta={'parent_url': response.url})

def parse_child(self, response):

    self.logger.info('-------------------------------------------')
    self.logger.info('Response From Parent URL : %s' %
                     response.meta['parent_url'])
    self.logger.info('Child Response URL : %s' % response.url)
    self.logger.info('Child Response Status : %s' % response.status)
    self.logger.info('-------------------------------------------')
```

## this is my code

When I run this, parse_parent only run in the class and parse_child doesn't appear as a result.
Is there any wrong codes?

Answer (score 0):

The function parse_child was called async, so the self is not "self" anymore.
You could try to convert parse_child to static function or class function.

Comment: well. Thank you for answering my question, but could you give me some specific examples?